# Add linebreak to text from Symfony2 Form Textarea

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

I have a Form with Symfony 2 with a textarea.

If the user writes something like this in the textarea

```
word1

word2 word3 word4
word5

rest of message
```

i'm getting the data exactly like this from the form, but without any HTML linebreaks. So if i want to use this text further for sending a email it'll be shown as this

```
word1 word3 word4 word5 rest of message
```

How can i save the formatting of the Text? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function:

```
$text = nl2br($text);

echo $text;
```

Comment: If it was persisted to the database like that then would the `<br />`'s appear in the textarea if they were to be edited in the future?

Comment: @Qoop yes - you would use this function for html display only. The text area should show the existing carriage returns as newlines anyway

Comment: Well, i thought that this function won't work because i couldn't see any `nl` tags in the returned text but its working just fine, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If you are wanting to use this in a Twig template then you should use the `nl2br` filter like..

```
{{ text|nl2br }} // NOT "bl2br" as I had originally written.
```

Comment: Totally correct, but it must be `nl2br` of course: `{{ text|nl2br }}`.