# Replacing linebreak in Textarea to <br/> doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony

On my Symfony website, **when i send a comment like this**:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

**It is displayed like this**:

```
line 1 line 2 line 3
```

**So** i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32661036/18441633) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865652/18441633) one **but they didn't solve my question:** I added nl2br to my code but the printed result is like this:

```
line 1<br /> line 2<br /> line 3
```

Here my code that i will simplify as follow:

Here my **article.html.twig**:

```php
    {% for comment in comments|reverse %}
      <h4>{{ comment.title }}</h4>
      <p>{{ comment.message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <h4>Leave your message</h4>
    {{ form(formComment) }}
```

So here my **Comment.php**:

```
public function getMessage(): ?string {
  return $this->message;
}

public function setMessage(string $message): self {
  $this->message = nl2br($message);  //nl2br is in test
  return $this;
}
```

Here my **CommentType.php**:

```
class CommentType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder,array $options): void {
  $builder
    ->add('title')
    ->add('message') //Here
    ->add('send', SubmitType::class);
}
```

Comment: remove the nl2br, it wont be rendered as HTML but rather `&lt;br/&gt;` because the template engine will htmlentities the message, so instead simply use CSS so newlines are treated like new lines, so `<p class="text-pre">` then add a class `.text-pre{ white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word;}`

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is working.
Did we have to reopen the question for you to post your answer? (since I already say that none of the answer in the other question resolve my question.)
If yes, how do we do that?